# Error installing sqlite3 gem

Tags: sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I tried install the sqlite3 gem via the following command line:

```
gem install sqlite3
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: undefined method `path2class' for #<Psych::ClassLoader:0x00000101269b78> (NoMethodError) in /Users/Peter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/cache/sqlite3-1.3.8.gem
```

I've tried the previous versions but all of the them give the same error. Removing the cache doesn't solve it either.

Any help is appreciated.

PS: I'm running this under OSX Mavericks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the gem at /Users/Peter/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/cache/sqlite3-1.3.8.gem.  RubyGems didn't download it properly (and improperly didn't reset the download). Try installing it again, it should work now.

Comment: How do you go about locating the corrupted gem file in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Asking just in case but, do you have SQLite3 installed? The gem needs it to work. You can get it from http://www.sqlite.org/ ([According to rubygems](http://rubygems.org/gems/sqlite3)). You also need SQLite 3.6.16 or newer for the latest version of the gem to work.

Comment: I edited my question to include the fact that I'm on OSX Mavericks :)